# Insert if not exists a row on database sqlite android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Is it possible? I used replace and it removed data from all referencing tables that have foreign key constraint on the row. which wasnt my intention...

How to do it right?

Comment: please give more clear idea about your problem..provide some code if possible

Answer (score 0):

You can use "ON CONFLICT IGNORE" as the constraint resolver in your insert statement. You can check this http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html

Example,

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO YourTable (item_id,item_title) values (1,'title')
```